# Trazer três possíveis resultados com Lambda

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, linq, expressões-lambda

Preciso em uma única expressão, trazer três possíveis resultados. Se data for até 15dd, retorna 1, se estiver entre 15 e 45 dd retorna 2 e se for maior que 45 retorna 3. Essa é minha lambda e o campo data correspondente.

```
var resultado = webDB.T_Controle_Importacao.Where(ci => ci.DataTransacao....)
```

Como eu trago três possíveis resultados?

Comment: Só mais uma pergunta. Numa lambda não se aceita && ou AND, eu tenho que fazer tantos where quantos são meus and(&&) certo?

Comment: Não tem problema em usar esses operadores.

Comment: Sua questão não está ainda muito clara para mim. Você poderia explicar melhor para que servem estes valores (1, 2 e 3)? Poderia exemplificar em que contexto serão usados esses valores?

Comment: Preciso desses valores, para indicar ao usuário o status desse cnpj. São esses tres status(1,2 e 3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar a sintaxe do LINQ para facilitar na criação de um valor que contém a diferença, usando `let`, e então usar esse valor calculado no `select` para retornar os valores que você quer, usando o operador condicional ternário (i.e. `cond ? a : b`):

```
var resultado = (from ci in webDB.T_Controle_Importacao
                 let dd = EntityFunctions.DiffDays(DateTime.Now, ci.DataTransacao)
                 select dd >= 45 ? 3
                      : dd >= 15 ? 2
                      :            1
                ).ToList();
```

Comment: Se esta query não retornar nada é porque `webDB.T_Controle_Importacao` não possui nenhum item, pois não há nenhum filtro sobre estes dados.

Comment: Talvez seja a falta do `ToList`, que fez você achar que nenhum dado foi retornado.

Comment: Você está usando qual ORM? É o EntityFramework?

Comment: Entity Framework, só não garanto dizer a versão, mas é a versão do VS 2012

Comment: Editei para efetuar a subtração de datas usando uma função do próprio DB: [`EntityFunctions.DiffDays`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412615.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Acho que assim funciona:

```
.Where(w => w.DataTransacao == (w.DataTransacao.AddDays(45) >= new DateTime(2014, 5, 5) ? 3 : w.DataTransacao.AddDays(15) <= new DateTime(2014, 5, 5) ? 1 : 2 ))
```

Somente lembrando de trocar new DateTime(2014, 5, 5) pela sua data padrão.

Explicando:

Se for a maior data, já coloca 3, senão verifica se for menor que 15, coloca 1 senão final é a clausula do meio com resultado 2.

Comment: O AddDays não funciona nesse contexto de código